# Are there more standard patterns besides diamonds which will preserve quad only meshes?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, topology

In order to bridge two edge loops having an unequal number of edges the diamond pattern can be used. [Video tutorials by Jonathan Williamson](http://cgcookie.com/blender/cgc-courses/learning-mesh-topology-collection/).

Are there more patterns that preserve the quads?

[image]

Steps:

1. Select 3 vertices (Image 1)
2. Merge at Center
3. Select another 3 vertices connected to the ones selected in step 1.
4. Merge the in 3. selected vertices. (Image 2)
5. Remove the superfluous (single edge) edge loop (Image 3, to illustrate how the edge flow is redirected)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually one can catch such topologycal tricks by watching
the vertices (poles) neighbour count. In your example there
is a cube which has one vertex with 5 neighbour and another
with 3. The following example shows one where these poles
are neighbours. As Hount House notet in his comment,
sometimes they are called N-poles and E-poles.

[image: Example]

When avoiding triangles, you can reduce or increase edge amount
somewhere by the cost of doing it somewhere else. In your example
on the same side you loose one and another edge. In my example I
added a new edge in the right side, and had to redirect the loop
Flow to the top. When simply removing an edge loop, you take
one edge from one side and one from the front side.

Generall, when using only quads on manifold meshes, every sub-mesh
of it (for example strangly subdivided planes like these) must have
even number of border edges (only one face connected). So a hole
with odd number of edges cannot be filled with quads.

Maybe I am getting too wild now. I am currently
working on a trees retopology, where you can see,
that I mostly only have the usual poles or E-poles.

[image: Second]

A similar example to yours (two edges taken
from bottom side), but with another loop Flow:

[image: Third]

Must note the tutorial in [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3004) related
question. I Recommend to watch all episode.

Comment: You have also poles with 3 neighbors. Someone once coined the phrase E-poles and N-poles because E has 5 and N has 3 strokes. It's the old 'cube on a subdivided plane' topology where you have E-poles at the base and N-poles at the top.