# What are the options to extrude fingers from a low poly hand?

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

The technique I currently use to create faces to extrude fingers from a base mesh is: Cut the front and upper faces with the knife tool (as shown in the image).

Using the knife tool creates n-gons which influences the topology, creating more loopcuts would be continue over the arms to the whole body where they are not really needed (and would create more work to adjust them).

[image]

Are there any alternative techniques?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Topology for hand models in general or just low poly hands? Also, how low do you mean by low poly?

Comment: @CharlesL Added more info to the question, is this now more clear what I'm asking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use *inset*, but I have only tried this for three fingered hands:

1. *Individual inset* (<kbd>I</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>) with both faces selected:

   [image]
2. Select the faces inside the new inset, move them forward a bit, inset again:

   [image]
3. Select the faces inside that inset and move them forward, extrude middle section:

   [image]

Extrude fingers:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using gandalf3 answer and combining it with a [diamond shape](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2995/are-there-more-standard-patterns-besides-diamonds-which-will-preserve-quad-only) which splits one loop-cut to three I found this all-quads solution:

[image]