# What are the most efficient workflows to create all quad junctions?

Tags: mesh, topology

In a video tutorial on [All Quad Junctions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3mm5sbMnpE) some different  types of junctions are explained. When trying to create them I struggle with extra edges and merging points, ripping points. That takes too much time

Is there a efficient reproduceable way to create these types of junctions?

[image]

Comment: Ah, I see you found a good tutorial.
That, and the related videos look useful.

Comment: You could use the *Knife* tool, you just have to be careful to avoid making n-gons.

Comment: link is broken. "Video is unavailable"

Comment: @Vader Sorry about that, it was demonstrating how the edge flow is influenced and how to have diamonds and 3 to 5 junctions as all quad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way that comes to mind currently is to remove  the critical faces, add some loop cuts, then create faces.

So for the second one, you would remove the critical face,
make a double loop cut with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>
then <kbd>2</kbd> then extrude the small edge in the middle,
and finally select the edge pairs to Fill them with <kbd>F</kbd>.

The same applies to the third and fourth with some changes. For
the first one: Remove the upper two critical faces, add the loop
cuts, fill the proper edge pairs, move the center vertex down.

Comment: Still pretty messy, would be cool to create an addon
that create and manipulate these patters with one key.

Answer (score 8):

IMHO, the most effective way would be like this:

**For the 1st case:**

Method 1:

[image]

Method 2:

[image]

Method 3 (more effective for continuous editing):

[image]

**For the 2nd, 3rd and 4th case:**

Select target area, then <kbd>I</kbd> to inset, uncheck **Boundary** in <kbd>F6</kbd> panel.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice GIFs, but they are to freaking fast to follow!

Comment: @CoDEmanX Ah, right, I just wanna show how effective they are. :P. Maybe a bit fast. OK. I've slowed them down. :)

Answer (score 7):

For the 4th case I found this workflow most convienent:

[image]

1. Poke one face <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> basically to limit loop-cuts in next step
2. Add the loop-cuts
3. Remove the middle vertex of the face 'poked' in step 1.
4. Extrude the points from the loop-cuts ends and create the required faces.

[image]

3rd case:

1. Poke two faces side by side <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> basically to limit loop-cuts in next step
2. Add the loop-cuts
3. Remove edges
4. Subdivide the middle edge
5. Add edges and finally faces