# Extrude and subdivide without using tris

Tags: modeling, topology

How do I extrude this top so the mesh will form a complete dress. More precisely, after applying the mirror modifier, each horizontal loop contains N=24 vertexes. To get good results from the cloth simulator, I want the skirt to have at least more vertexes around each horizontal loop so I need to branch each vertical edge to create more vertexes in the loop below. Is it possible to join two loops with N and kN vertexes without using a "tris bridge". That is, I want to stick to quads.

Update:

I figured out that I can multiply by three using the following pattern

```
|      |
+------+
 \    / \
  +--+   +
 /|  |\ /
+ |  | +
| |  | |
+-+--+-+
```

By only branching every other edge, it is possible to multiply by two.

This technique results in some bad quads. Is more regular tris a better approach then?

[image: My mesh]

Comment: Can you be a little more specific with what you are trying to accomplish? Maybe sketch it over the image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways to increase vertex count between edge loops using all quads.

[image]

And a quick trick for the right one using inset.

1. Set face select mode
2. Select two faces at the end you want to expand loop cuts.
3. Press <kbd>I</kbd> and inset a small amount 
   [image]
4. Select next two faces and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>
5. Repeat step 4
6. Select all new internal faces 
   [image]
7. press <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>
8. repeat 6 and 7 a few times
9. Set vertex select mode and box select the bottom vertices and delete

[image]

If you have a fully round mesh like your dress you can get around this step if you apply the mirror modifier and disable boundary in the inset options when doing the first inset. You can then delete half the dress and re-add the mirror modifier.

I now have a mesh that starts with 5 vertices at the top and ends with 37 at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: more examples on how to deal with quads: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/what-are-the-most-efficient-workflows-to-create-all-quad-junctions