# How to connect objects if they don't match?

Tags: modeling

Hey I want to connect these ears to this head. The thing is I want to rig it later and I'm worried that if I don't actually join the two meshes together it will look weird if I move the ears with a joint. Would it work regardless or do I need to connect both meshes. If I have to connect them the problem I have is that obviously there are aren't enough vertices on the head to properly connect the ears to it. I know about adding a new edge or also subdividing so that's really no problem. What I want to know is if this is absolutely necessary or if there's a way to connect these 2 objects together without doing this.

[image]

Comment: It might look strange if you want the ear to bend, but it's hard to say. There is really no way to connect mismatching geometry without making a mess of tris (if you don't mind tris, then try the bridge tool; `W`> Bridge edge loops). Since it's kind of hard to make separate objects which match perfectly, I think the easier solution is to extrude the ear out of head.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. Just to make sure tris are faces with only 3 edges correct? Another thing is I see people model online but they do  it face by face. I might just start doing that. It looks like it takes a lot more skill but it also seems to eliminate a lot of problems

Comment: Yes, that's a tri(angle). Here is a [list of tutorials on blender.org](http://www.blender.org/support/tutorials/) covering many topics, including modeling. Also see the [beginner's reference](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/43/599), which lists many good tutorial sites. Hope it helps :)

Comment: There are ways to join edge loops with different vertex counts, basically you have one or more loops that alter the vertex count. [This answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8853/extrude-and-subdivide-without-using-tris/8874#8874) shows some ways to do that and links to another post with more examples.