# Optimizing Mesh to Quads only

Tags: modeling, vertices, faces

Often when I model objects with circular areas, I run into trouble converting ngons and tris into quads. The selected face is a quad, but it has this "open" vert, and those often causes problems when e.g. beveling. Any tips on dealing with such tricky situations? I'm pretty fresh 3D user. All help appreciated!

I could make this one, big ngon face, but I really want to get into good modeling habits.

[image: problem]

solid view of the model

[image: solid view of the model]

Comment: This may be helpful http://topologyguides.com/

Comment: You should expect to have more geometry on the surrounding shape to get a hole with that many verts. You usually don't need that many verts, a subsurf can smooth the circle better than the extra verts. [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8874/935) shows some examples that may be of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Link provided by Duarte Farrajota Ramos is great place to find topology tips (I'm using it by myself) but sometimes you can't find technical aspects of how to create particular topology.

Before I start I want to encourage you to look for good topology without focusing on specific app. Good topology is good, no matter which software was used.

You can achieve it in several ways, I'll show you the quickest one I've found, possible with LoopTools addon (you can find it in User Preferences) wich is shipped with Blender.

### Final result:

[image: final]

### Quick method:

[image: method]

1. Press <kbd>W</kbd> > **Subdivide** to subdivide a **Plane**.
2. Delete center Vertex.
3. Select **Edge Loop**.
4. <kbd>E</kbd> to **Extrude** then <kbd>S</kbd> to **Scale** it.
5. <kbd>W</kbd> > **LoopTools** > **Circle**.
6. Add **Subdivision Modifier**.
7. (Optional as needed) Use **Bevel** or **Mean Crease** on edges.

In my example I've used **Bevel** with 3 segments on inner circle edge and corner edges of shape, also I've used **Mirror modifier**. Everything was made from simple **Plane**.

### Extension (technique without addon):

I've thought that maybe for some reason you don't want to use any addons so here is a method without it.

[image: second]

> 1-4 steps are the same as in first method.

5. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> > **At Center**.
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to **Bevel only Vertex** and scale it as needed.
7. <kbd>X</kbd> > **Only Faces** to delete central face.